Sendgrid integration throwing error on .NET 4.5.2
I have an old version of a project, based on .NET 4.5.2.
I am trying to integrate Sendgrid to send email, but I get an error.
Here's my code which I have tried and also causes the error. Can anyone help me?
public void Email_ALL()
{
     try
     {
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
         ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

         var sendclient = new SendGridClient("api-key");
         var from = new EmailAddress("hello@test.com", "Test");
         var subject = "Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun";
         var to = new EmailAddress("Test@gmail.com", "Example User");
         var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
         var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
         var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

         var result = Task.Run(() => sendclient.SendEmailAsync(msg)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
}

The error I am facing is shown here, and I've also attached a screenshot for clarification:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.'
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host



Why do you use Tls12 then immediately downgrade it to Tls11? See this. Side note, throw ex is a bad idea because it resets the stack trace, and .NET Framework 4.5.2 when out of support 2 years ago.

I have removed Tls11 code.. zi know 4.5.2 is out of support.. Client has old project so need to work in that

Would be good consulting practice to suggest upgrading the project while at it.

If the exception is happening on the line with sendclient.SendEmailAsync(msg), then chances are high that there's some configured server that your workstation is unable to reach.  In these situations, I would use Fiddler (Telerik) or Wireshark to inspect the network traffic.  Find out what server and port number the code is trying to reach.

You may have an outbound firewall concern
The SendGrid client code may need to be updated, or some configuration file changed to point it to a more current list of servers
Some other network related issue

If you can determine server / IP and port number, try connecting to the server from a command prompt by using the Telnet application (it's built into Windows, but is not available by default) and the same server name and port number.  If you can't connect from Telnet, then your code won't be able to, either.
